# Hiding a table row (the ItemPlaceholderID row) in a ListView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a table row that holds my paging controls in a `ListView` as follows (partial layout):

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvOrderItems" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="odsShoppingCart"
    DataKeyNames="ProductNumber"
    ItemPlaceholderID="lvItemContainer">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="lvCart" runat="server">
            <tr id="lvHeader" runat="server">
            ...
            </tr>
            <tr id="lvItemContainer" runat="server"></tr>
            <tr id="lvPaging" runat="server">
            ...
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
```

In my code-behind, I handle the DataBound event as follows, and I am planning on hiding the entire `lvItemContainer` row conditionally (for now, I am just trying to hide the row itself without conditions):

```
Protected Sub lvOrderItems_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lvOrderItems.DataBound
    Dim lvItemContainer As HtmlTableRow = CType(lvOrderItems.FindControl("lvItemContainer"), HtmlTableRow)
    If Not lvItemContainer Is Nothing Then
        Response.Write("hit1")
        lvItemContainer.Visible = False
    End If

    Dim lvPaging As HtmlTableRow = CType(lvOrderItems.FindControl("lvPaging"), HtmlTableRow)
    If Not lvPaging Is Nothing Then
        Response.Write("hit2")
        lvPaging.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

So when this runs on `DataBound`, `hit1` is never fired, but `hit2` is... any ideas what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attempting to (unsuccessfully) adjust the visibility of the `ItemPlaceholderID` container, I've set the visibility of the individual rows in the container.

Answer (score 3):

HTML purists don't like it, but this approach works:

**In the OnLayoutCreated event, try one of the following approaches:**

Take the **runat="server" out of the table and child rows**, and do this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlItemContainer" runat="server">
    <tr id="lvItemContainer"></tr>
</asp:Panel>

pnlItemContainer.Visible = false;
```

Or you can do this:

```
<tr id="lvItemContainer" runat="server"></tr>
```

**EDIT**: Embedded style element because setting visible to false does not work in the layout template.

```
lvItemContainer.Style["display"] = "none";
```

I'm not sure how it will work with a layout template, but it's worked for me in other situations.

Comment: ListView is squawking that it expects a TableRow... `Value of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow'`

Comment: Take the runat="server" out of the table declaration (and child elements), or just set the visibility of the row to false, since you have it running at the server level.

Comment: I have set the `Visible = False` from code-behind, but no luck. In reading more about the ListView control, it looks like the ListView replaces the `ItemPlaceholderID` content with the actual items themselves... so maybe when the ListView is constructed, <tr id="lvItemContainer" runat="server"></tr> is being replaced with the rows, which would explain why setting is to invisible doesn't work (as it isn't a part of the final control anyways?)

Comment: Hmm, well I get `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"` as it looks like lvItemContainer is simply not available from the code behind on data bind, as it has been replaced by the rows of items.

Comment: Okay, let's try this again. See edited answer. Put your logic in the OnLayoutCreated event, as you should be able to access the control from there.

Comment: Sorry, not working... very strange. I posted my workaround solution below.